# How to find RGB value of a segmentation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, rgb

[image]

I try to find de mean RGB value of the segmentation in the picture enclosed.

Probably I have to transform it to a numpy array and save this numpy as csv file but i don't know how.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with relevant documentation, user guides and tutorials then try to implement something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/) library

```
pip install scikit-image
```

Read and find mean

```
from skimage import io
image = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTcXE.jpg')
```

Mean RGB values for all pixels in the image

```
image.mean(axis=0).mean(axis=0)
```

[image]

Mean RGB values for pixels excluding black pixels in an image

```
image[np.all(image != 0, axis=2)].mean(axis=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
I am using Pycharm and when i run this code the output is: Process finished with exit code 0.  Any idea where I can find RGB values?

Comment: I am quit new at Python so even the basics are sometimes hard to find;) But I found it. The problem is, this gives me the mean RGB of the whole image. Is there some code to filter the black background? @Vishnudev